# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, arraylist, casting

I am trying to compare two Exel files however cant get around the exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.String'."
Exception on the below code.

The problem is that the intersect data is not being added in intersection Variable below after intersecting both files.

```
try
{
    foreach (var i in existingLead.Cast<string>().Intersect(newLead.Cast<string>()))
    {
        intersection.Add(i);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "In Intersection Array", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

The complete Class Here. This class is initiated in Form1 class On Button Click. after the user selects two excel files. It takes the file path from the respective textboxes for the filepath

```
class Compare
{
    public ArrayList existingLead = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList newLead = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList intersection = new ArrayList();

    public void FindDuplicates(string filePathExisting, string filePathNew)
    {
        List<DataTable> existingDataTableList = ImportExcel(filePathExisting);
        List<DataTable> newDataTableList = ImportExcel(filePathNew);

        foreach (var item in existingDataTableList)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in item.Rows)
            {
                //add to array
                existingLead.Add(row);
            }

        }

        foreach (var item in newDataTableList)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in item.Rows)
            {
                //add to array
                newLead.Add(row);
            }

        }

        try
        {
            foreach (var i in existingLead.Cast<string>().Intersect(newLead.Cast<string>()))
            {
                intersection.Add(i);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "In Intersection Array", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }



        }

    private List<DataTable> ImportExcel(string FileName)
    {
        List<DataTable> _dataTables = new List<DataTable>();
        string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
        string _Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        //Checking for the extentions, if XLS connect using Jet OleDB
        if (_Extension != null)
        {
            if (_Extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                _ConnectionString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            }
            //Use ACE OleDb
            else if (_Extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || _Extension != null)
            {
                _ConnectionString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File extensoin must be .xls or .xlsx", "Incompatible File Type", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }


        DataTable dataTable = null;

        using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection =
            new OleDbConnection(string.Format(_ConnectionString, FileName)))
        {
            if (oleDbConnection != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    oleDbConnection.Open();
                    //Getting the meta data information.
                    //This DataTable will return the details of Sheets in the Excel File.
                    DataTable dbSchema = oleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info, null);
                    foreach (DataRow item in dbSchema.Rows)
                    {
                        //reading data from excel to Data Table
                        using (OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand())
                        {
                            oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;
                            oleDbCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]",
                                item["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                            {
                                oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = oleDbCommand;
                                dataTable = new DataTable(item["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                                oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                                _dataTables.Add(dataTable);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show( e.Message, "Querying Data Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection String Empty", "No Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        return _dataTables;
    }
```

Comment: Well what are the types of `existingLead` and `newLead`? You haven't shown us any of the declarations, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: What is `existingLead`?  What is `newLead`?  You need to edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ExistingLead and NewLead are ArrayLists which contains data from respective exel Sheet. Will edit my question with more code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Between the casts and the datarow instance:

```
existingLead.Cast<string>() ...
```

tell it which col of the data row you want

```
existingLead["ColName"].Cast<string>() ...
```

or existinglead.item("ColName") or however DataRow does that.

Comment: Is `existingLead` a DataRow?  OP has not specified _what_ it is, so this answer could very well be 100% inaccurate...

Comment: what my answer 100% inaccurate? wouldn't be the first time ;-) just ask my brother. But something tells me it might be a datarow (cue the mysterious music)

Comment: We r comparing different excel files all the time and table name is not known to specify